# How do I make this jquery code less redundant and more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I'm relatively new to writing javascript. The js code below is modified from a previous answer I found on here. It does exactly what I want it to do functionality-wise, however, it's redundant and calling the code every time the mouse enters (which takes more resources than it needs too).

Any suggestions on how to make this less redundant and more efficient?

**SIMPLIFIED DEMO HERE:** http://jsfiddle.net/nsnzd9cL/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="category" id="commercials">
        <p>Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />
        </p>
        <div class="scroll">
            <p>Scroll</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="photography">
        <p>Something
            <br />Something
            <br />
        </p>
        <div class="scroll">
            <p>Scroll</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="experiments">
        <p>Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />Something
            <br />
        </p>
        <div class="scroll">
            <p>Scroll</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  var arrow1 = $('#commercials .scroll');
var arrow2 = $('#photography .scroll');
var arrow3 = $('#experiments .scroll');

$("#commercials").mouseenter(function () {

    if ($('#commercials').hasScrollBar()) {
        arrow1.css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });
    } else {
        arrow1.css({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
    }
});

$("#photography").mouseenter(function () {

    if ($('#photography').hasScrollBar()) {
        arrow2.css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });
    } else {
        arrow2.css({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
    }
});

$("#experiments").mouseenter(function () {

    if ($('#experiments').hasScrollBar()) {
        arrow3.css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });
    } else {
        arrow3.css({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
    }
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > (this.height() + 1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsnzd9cL/2/)

Bind the event to the container and apply it to the elements within the container, in this case the specified IDs.  Then look up elements relative to the target when triggered:

```
$('.container').on('mouseenter','#commercials,#photography,#experiments', function(){
    var $this   = $(this),
        $scroll = $this.find('.scroll');

    if( $this.hasScrollBar() ){
        $scroll.css('visibility','visible');
    } else {
        $scroll.css('visibility','hidden');
    }   
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > (this.height() + 1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

but really, I'd replace the `'#commercials,#photography,#experiments'` with `'.category'`; [JSFiddle using .category](http://jsfiddle.net/ftreq8cL/).

Using `.category` gives you the added benefit of adding new categories dynamically and not having to rebind events when they're created after the page load, since the event is still on the container.

Comment: Perfect. Your suggestion with .category work beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have reduce all the redundancy I could find:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > (this.height() + 1);
    }

    var $commercials = $( "#commercials" ),
        $photography = $( "#photography" ),
        $experiments = $( "#experiments" );

    var mouseEnterListner = function() {
        var arrow = $(this).find( '.scroll' );

        if ( $(this).hasScrollBar() ) {
            arrow.css({
                'visibility': 'visible'
            });
        } else {
            arrow.css({
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            });
        };
    };

    $commercials.on('mouseenter', function() {
        mouseEnterListner.call(this);
    });

    $photography.on('mouseenter', function() {
        mouseEnterListner.call(this);
    });

    $experiments.on('mouseenter', function() {
        mouseEnterListner.call(this);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: You can simplify further by selecting all the elements at once

Comment: Yep, if those IDs have a common className e.g: `.content-block`, then the `.on()` only need to be added just once. Although I kept the original code as close as possible to the @Zach's since we are dealing with `mouseenter` event and any `div` overlapping can create some nasty effects ;)

Comment: See my answer for what I mean

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it...

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsnzd9cL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    scrollCheck();
});

function scrollCheck() {
    var div = '',
        scroll = true;
    $('.category').each(function( index ) {
        div = $(this);
        scroll = div.get(0).scrollHeight <= (div.height() + 1);
        console.log(scroll); // just a check
        if (scroll) {
            div.children('.scroll').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy to read and non redundant code:**

```
var arrow1 = $('#commercials .scroll');
var arrow2 = $('#photography .scroll');
var arrow3 = $('#experiments .scroll');

function bindMouseEnter(id, arrow){

   $("#"+id).mouseenter(function () {

       if ($('#'+id).hasScrollBar()) {
          arrow.css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
          });
      } else {
        arrow.css({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
      }
    });

}

bindMouseEnter('commercials', arrow1);
bindMouseEnter('photography', arrow2);
bindMouseEnter('experiments', arrow3);


(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > (this.height() + 1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Continueing from Vijay's answer, we can combine the selector:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > (this.height() + 1);
    }

    $("#commercials,#photography,#experiments").on('mouseenter', function() {
        var arrow = $(this).find('.scroll');

        if ( $(this).hasScrollBar() ) {
            arrow.css({
                'visibility': 'visible'
            });
        } else {
            arrow.css({
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            });
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```